# Discretization with non-constant matrix containg entries form unknown vector

Tags: linear-algebra, pde, ode, finite-volume, discretization

Consider a system of PDEs
$$
\begin{cases}
u_t = \nabla \cdot (D(u)\nabla u) + \frac{c}{K_U+c}u-ku\\
c_t = d_c\Delta c -\frac{\nu_U c}{K_U + c}u
\end{cases}
$$
with some boundary conditions. Here, $D(u)$ is a diffusion coefficient which depends on $u$; $K_U$, $\nu_U$ and $k$ are some constants. $D(u)$ can be defined as, for example,

$$D(u):=\delta \frac{u^\alpha}{(1-u)^\beta},$$
with $\alpha,\beta,\delta$ being some constants.

After this system of PDEs is discretized using the finite volume method one obtains the following system of ODEs

$$\begin{cases}\frac{d\vec{U}}{dt}=\underline{D(\vec{U})}\vec{U}+\underline{R_U(\vec{C})}\vec{U}\\
\frac{d\vec{C}}{dt}=\underline{L}\vec{C}-\underline{R_C(\vec{C})}\vec{U}+\vec{b}
\end{cases}$$

where the underlined letters are matrices and $\vec{b}$ is a vector containing some terms from (unspecified here) the boundary conditions.

As we can see, the matrix $\underline{D(\vec{U})}$ depends on the vector for which a numerical method will solve this system of equations, that is the vector $\vec{U}$.

But then how can such a system be solved linearly if it will contain non-linear terms? I.e. what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Nonlinear systems of equations are in general not solvable exactly. What you need to do is to use a method to solve nonlinear systems, of which there are of course quite a lot:

- A simple approach would be to use $D(U)\approx D(U^{n-1})$, where $D^{n-1}$ is the solution of the previous time step.
- A possibly smarter approach would be to use $D(U)\approx D(U^{\ast})$, where $D^{\ast}$ is extrapolated from the previous time steps.
- Probably even better is to use a Newton iteration.

The first of these are "explicit" methods, whereas the last one is implicit.

Comment: Thanks. But how are numerical linear algebra methods applied in a case like this one to solve a system, without thinking about time steps but only the spatial variables? Even if we equated the time derivatives in the ODE system to 0 we would still get some nonlinear terms because $D(U)$ is multiplied by $U$.

Comment: @sequence: You're starting from the wrong point. You can't even apply numerical linear algebra methods if you had a *linear* problem where $D$ does not depend on $U$, if you didn't want to do time stepping. ODEs can only be solved numerically if you *do* use time stepping. Nonlinear problems just make the problem you solve in each time step a bit more complicated.